# Generate new distribution from auto-encoder /variational autoencoder

Tags: autoencoder, vae

I know that autoencoders can be used to generate new data.
From what I could understand..
The autoencoder uses the original distribution X to learn a random gaussian distribution described by mean and sigma.

Then the decoder will use the mean and sigma parameters to randomly sample a new parameter which will be close to X.

My question is  that let's say I have information about two features X and Y.Then can I use the variational auto encoder to generate new random samples related to Y using X.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of autoencoders is denoising, i.e. creating clean data from that could include either noisy, wrong or missing values.

Consequently, you may want to create new data with an autoencoder that applies a probabilistic approach to "guess" what the imperfect data is.

Therefore, you can use a dropout function that will erase some data in order to test the model quality.

Here is a code example for sequential data:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.objectives import mse
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dropout, Dense
from keras.regularizers import l1l2
from collections import defaultdict
%matplotlib inline

class Autoencoder:
    def __init__(self, data,
                 recurrent_weight=0.5,
                 optimizer="adam",
                 dropout_probability=0.5,
                 hidden_activation="relu",
                 output_activation="sigmoid",
                 init="glorot_normal",
                 l1_penalty=0,
                 l2_penalty=0):
        self.data = data.copy()
        self.recurrent_weight = recurrent_weight
        self.optimizer = optimizer
        self.dropout_probability = dropout_probability
        self.hidden_activation = hidden_activation
        self.output_activation = output_activation
        self.init = init
        self.l1_penalty = l1_penalty
        self.l2_penalty = l2_penalty
    def _get_hidden_layer_sizes(self):
        n_dims = self.data.shape[1]
        return [
            min(2000, 8 * n_dims),
            min(500, 2 * n_dims),
            int(np.ceil(0.5 * n_dims)),
        ]
    def _create_model(self):
        hidden_layer_sizes = self._get_hidden_layer_sizes()
        first_layer_size = hidden_layer_sizes[0]
        n_dims = self.data.shape[1]
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(
            first_layer_size,
            input_dim= 2 * n_dims,
            activation=self.hidden_activation,
            W_regularizer=l1l2(self.l1_penalty, self.l2_penalty),
            init=self.init))
        model.add(Dropout(self.dropout_probability))
        for layer_size in hidden_layer_sizes[1:]:
            model.add(Dense(
                layer_size,
                activation=self.hidden_activation,
                W_regularizer=l1l2(self.l1_penalty, self.l2_penalty),
                init=self.init))
            model.add(Dropout(self.dropout_probability))
        model.add(Dense(
            n_dims,
            activation=self.output_activation,
            W_regularizer=l1l2(self.l1_penalty, self.l2_penalty),
            init=self.init))
        loss_function = make_reconstruction_loss(n_dims)
        model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer, loss=loss_function)
        return model
    def fill(self, missing_mask):
        self.data[missing_mask] = -1
    def _create_missing_mask(self):
        if self.data.dtype != "f" and self.data.dtype != "d":
            self.data = self.data.astype(float)
        return np.isnan(self.data)
    def _train_epoch(self, model, missing_mask, batch_size):
        input_with_mask = np.hstack([self.data, missing_mask])
        n_samples = len(input_with_mask)
        n_batches = int(np.ceil(n_samples / batch_size))
        indices = np.arange(n_samples)
        np.random.shuffle(indices)
        X_shuffled = input_with_mask[indices]
        for batch_idx in range(n_batches):
            batch_start = batch_idx * batch_size
            batch_end = (batch_idx + 1) * batch_size
            batch_data = X_shuffled[batch_start:batch_end, :]
            model.train_on_batch(batch_data, batch_data)
        return model.predict(input_with_mask)
    def train(self, batch_size=256, train_epochs=100):
        missing_mask = self._create_missing_mask()
        self.fill(missing_mask)
        self.model = self._create_model()
        observed_mask = ~missing_mask
        for epoch in range(train_epochs):
            X_pred = self._train_epoch(self.model, missing_mask, batch_size)
            observed_mae = masked_mae(X_true=self.data,
                                    X_pred=X_pred,
                                    mask=observed_mask)
            if epoch % 50 == 0:
                print("observed mae:", observed_mae)
            old_weight = (1.0 - self.recurrent_weight)
            self.data[missing_mask] *= old_weight
            pred_missing = X_pred[missing_mask]
            self.data[missing_mask] += self.recurrent_weight * pred_missing
        return self.data.copy()
```

Source: https://curiousily.com/posts/data-imputation-using-autoencoders/

Of course, you need enough data to have a correct prediction, but autoencoders could work even with a small dataset, only if the dataset is representative enough of potential tests scenarios.

You way also want to implement ranges of uncertainty to know the results reliability, using the maximum likelyhood for example.

Comment: thanks,that helps